# Creating NaN values in Pandas (instead of Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm converting a .ods spreadsheet to a Pandas DataFrame. I have whole columns and rows I'd like to drop because they contain only "None". As "None" is a `str`, I have:

`pandas.DataFrame.replace("None", numpy.nan)`

...on which I call: `.dropna(how='all')`

Is there a `pandas` equivalent to `numpy.nan`?

Is there a way to use `.dropna()` with the *string "None" rather than `NaN`?

Comment: Pandas uses `numpy.nan`. Pandas uses a lot of numpy data structures and algorithms under the covers.

Comment: How would I use it without importing numpy?

Comment: If you set a value in a float64 column to `None` this will be interpreted by `pandas` as a missing value, and will be replaced with `numpy.nan`.

Comment: It's not in fact a `None` type. It's a `str` that happens to be "None".

Comment: Ah you're right, but think it's still a `None`. Caveated the last comment.

Comment: I don't know how you're creating your dataframes, but there are ways of letting pandas know that you want to interpret some input values as `NaN`s.  See, for example, `pd.read_csv`'s `na_values` argument.

Comment: Calling `pd.DataFrame` on an array (because Pandas does not appear to support .ods). I see `na_values` in `pd.read_csv` but not in `pd.DataFrame`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you can do `pandas.np.nan`

Answer (score 8):

You can use `float('nan')` if you really want to avoid importing things from the numpy namespace:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
>>> s[1] = float('nan')
>>> s
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> s.dropna()
0    1.0
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Moreover, if you have a string value "None", you can `.replace("None", float("nan"))`:

```
>>> s[1] = "None"
>>> s
0       1
1    None
2       3
dtype: object
>>> 
>>> s.replace("None", float("nan"))
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use `dropna` on a value other than `nan`? Or is there some other method that does this?

Comment: Like, `.replace("None", np.nan)`?

Comment: I'd rather avoid `.replace()` altogether. I'm only using it because I want to use `dropna`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to drop directly the rows containing a "None" string value (without converting these "None" cells to `NaN` values), I guess it can be done without using `replace` + `dropna`

Considering a DataFrame like :

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({
            "foo": [1,2,3,4],
            "bar": ["None",5,5,6],
            "baz": [8, "None", 9, 10]
            })

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    bar   baz  foo
0  None     8    1
1     5  None    2
2     5     9    3
3     6    10    4
```

Using `replace` and `dropna` will return

```
In [5]: df.replace('None', float("nan")).dropna()
Out[5]: 
   bar   baz  foo
2  5.0   9.0    3
3  6.0  10.0    4
```

Which can also be obtained by simply selecting the row you need :

```
In [7]: df[df.eval("foo != 'None' and bar != 'None' and baz != 'None'")]
Out[7]: 
  bar baz  foo
2   5   9    3
3   6  10    4
```

You can also use the `drop` method of your dataframe, selecting appropriately the axis/labels targeted :

```
In [9]: df.drop(df[(df.baz == "None") |
                   (df.bar == "None") |
                   (df.foo == "None")].index)
Out[9]: 
  bar baz foo
2   5   9   3
3   6  10   4
```

These two methods are more or less interchangeable as you can also do for example:
`df[(df.baz != "None") & (df.bar != "None") & (df.foo != "None")]`
(but i guess the comparison df.somecolumns == "Some string" is only possible if the column type allows it, before theses last 2 examples, which wasn't the case with `eval`, i had to do `df = df.astype (object)` as the `foo` columns was of type `int64`)